# How to add character to beginning of regex matched string?

Tags: python, regex

I have some data (below) which I am trying to align.

```
| 24 | 11 | 506  | -1  | -829.99||
| 24 | 11 | 1910 | 506 | 1      | 829.99|3|
| 12 | 11 | 1933 | 531 | 2      | 7.78  |N|
```

It seems whenever the 3rd to last value for each row is negative, the row is missing a "|" delimiter. I am trying to use regex to add a vertical bar mid-way through the records to re-align the data like so:

```
| 24 | 11 |      | 506 | -1     | -829.99||
| 24 | 11 | 1910 | 506 | 1      | 829.99 | 3|
| 12 | 11 | 1933 | 531 | 2      | 7.78   | N|
```

Disregard the white space, I included it to make the data more readable for the purpose of this question.

I know the below expression will locate the correct text group and place an additional "|" after it but can this be modified to put the "|" before the group?

```
re.sub(r'(\|*\|*\|\|)', r'\1',DATA)
```

Just getting started with regex so any help is appreciated!

P.S. - I am using python to do the actual regex substitutions/additions for this data munging task.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your regex. The asterisk `*` indicates that the previous element (whether one character or compound) can repeat zero or more times. Therefore, `\|*` would match "" (empty string), "|", "||", etc. and `\|*\|*\|\|` would match two consecutive bars "||" preceded by any number of bars (0 or more) -- therefore, it matches the last two bars, only.

To prove this, with `re.sub`, you can surround the back-reference (i.e. `\1`) with some different characters (I used curly braces i.e. `{\1}` below).

```
data="""| 24 | 11 | 506  | -1  | -829.99||
| 24 | 11 | 1910 | 506 | 1      | 829.99|3|
| 12 | 11 | 1933 | 531 | 2      | 7.78  |N|
"""
print("using regex above, with curly braces around captured match:")
print(re.sub(r'(\|*\|*\|\|)', r'{\1}', data))

print("desired output:")
print(re.sub(r'(\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|\|)', r'|\1', data))
```

Output:

```
using regex above, with curly braces around captured match:
| 24 | 11 | 506  | -1  | -829.99{||}
| 24 | 11 | 1910 | 506 | 1      | 829.99|3|
| 12 | 11 | 1933 | 531 | 2      | 7.78  |N|

desired output:
| 24 | 11 || 506  | -1  | -829.99||
| 24 | 11 | 1910 | 506 | 1      | 829.99|3|
| 12 | 11 | 1933 | 531 | 2      | 7.78  |N|
```

The solution looks for bars with a positive number of items in between them, which are not bars. `[^|]` means anything other than `|` will match. Note that in the brackets, that bar does not need escaping. The `+` indicates "one or more of the previous element".

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you ? It gives me the desired output.

```
re.sub(r'(\|.*\|.*\|.*)(\|.*\|.*\|\|\n)',r'\g<1>'+'|'+r'\g<2>',DATA)
```

I kept everything before 506 in group 1 and everything after it in group 2 and added a '|' in between.